# How can I correct CUPS 'connection refused' error on chromebook?

Tags: connection, cups

I have installed CUPS on a new linux chromebook. It recognized my printers, and I used

```
    sudo system-config-printer
```

to install drivers and test. The printers all worked. But I was unable to access CUPS using the localhost:631 web page, so I rebooted the chromebook. After that, the printers still work and I still can't access the localhost interface, but now the `sudo system-config-printer` fails with

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(system-config-printer.py:658): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:11:20.173: cannot open display: :0
```

However, the simple `system-config-printer` command, without sudo, does bring up the CUPS gui window, although most functionality is unavailable. This feels like a permissions problem, but I can't find it.

Any help out there?

Comment: I found the local CUPS web page at penguin.local:631 but it's weird. It worked once yesterday, but it wouldn't work again. Today I rebooted, and after trying every 10-15 minutes, it finally worked. Once. Now it won't work anymore. CUPS service is enabled and active. What's going on??

Comment: And I forgot to add, "sudo system-config-printer" still does not work.